# Is it possible to perform SQL injection on a server that is using a database other than MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, security, sql-injection

If the database used by a server is something other than MySQL, say Mongo DB, then is it possible to execute SQL queries? In such cases how can we perform SQL injection? 
I don't expect all the possible commands, but some basic commands if the app is using, say MongoDB.

Comment: It is possible. Question is way too broad to answer it. SQL injection is not about deleting or destroying a data storage layer. It's also about finding holes in logic and abusing them. Therefore, any storage layer that uses SQL-like syntax is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: By definition a database that does not use SQL cannot be comprised using ***SQL** injection*. But I'm sure there are other vulnerabilities related to the query language that that specific database is using.

Comment: I have edited the question to reduce the broadness of the question. Please reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This type of attack is possible with any data source which parses queries. In the case of MongoDB, the queries are written in JavaScript instead of SQL but if you build your query like this:

```
 String query = "db.users.find({ age: " + request.getParameter("age") + " });"
```

then you open the database to similar kinds of attacks.

Answer (score 1):

This is nosql injection, and it is possible. 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_NoSQL_injection